# Activity gets reloaded after checking the App permissions when the back is pressed. Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have used the following code to check the app permissions. After the execution of this code if I am trying to finish my activity by using 'Finish()' but it is reloading the activity. Here is my code to check the permissions:

```
void CheckAppPermissions()
    {
        const string permission = Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage;
        if (Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, permission) == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
        {
            PDFGenerator();
            //Toast.MakeText(this, "access granted", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return;
        }
        if (Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "External storage permission required to save pdf", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

            Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 100);


    }
```

Here my code to finish activity

```
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                Finish();

                break;
        }

        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

I am not able to understand why the activity is reloading when the back is pressed in toolbar.

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `Finish()`. Can you maybe provide a bit more context?

Comment: I edited my code please have a look.